# Can i include the profile picture of inviting friend using fb send dialog

Tags: facebook, send

I want to invite friend of facebook for a app. Thats why i am using facebook send method. it works fine. but my new requirement is to show the friend picture who is being invited in the dialog window. please give me way to solve the problem.

Advance thanks to all

Comment: what language/framework you use?

Comment: I am using php/CI. But meanwhile i have got the solution. Immediately i will publish solution in my blog.

Comment: Here http://mayusuf.com/2013/06/16/can-i-include-the-profile-picture-of-inviting-friend-using-fb-send-dialog/ any one get the solution.